# Current role nodelets in the ROS ecosystem

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also posted a more technical code-related question about nodelets, but I felt this was a separate question.

As somebody who is used to designing image processing pipelines, nodelets make a lot of sense to me.  I have made efforts to minimize the number of data copies across a PCI bus (CPU <--> GPU), so the overhead of copying data between processes through the IP stack seems like a much larger concern.

However, I'm confused as to why the image_transport package does not seem to include any tutorials for using nodelets.  Also, the uvc_camera doesn't come with a nodelet version of the driver (althought the 1394 camera does).

So are nodelets not well supported at this time?  Or am I looking in all of the wrong places for documentation/examples?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244560/current-role-nodelets-in-the-ros-ecosystem/) by [rexroni](https://answers.ros.org/users/28047/rexroni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-27**:
Additional comment: comms through `localhost` are very efficient under Linux, so even though it will be more of a performance hit than using nodelets+zero-copy, it's nowhere near as bad as you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodelets are not mentioned in the image_transport docs because they don't depend on one another. zero-copy in nodelets is automatic, and image_transport is based on standard publishes and subscribers, so if you use image_transport within a nodelet, ROS will use the zero-copy transport; otherwise it will use the standard TCP-based transport.

Most of the camera drivers are maintained by different people or research groups, so they're not all the same. You may want to look for a different USB camera driver that does provide nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rexroni](https://answers.ros.org/users/28047/rexroni/) on 2016-09-26**:
I had previously tried a simple implementation with image_transport--the sort described in the image subscriber/publisher tutorials--but it refused to work.  I tried again, and it worked.  Thanks for the explanation.